# How to change shape of wx.TextCtrl widget in wxpython?

Tags: python, wxpython, wx.textctrl

i want to change the shape of wx.TextCtrl widget used in wxpython. normal by default shape is a square box but i want to make all the corner having round curve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not supported by the `wx.TextCtrl` out of the box. What you need to understand is that most of the core widgets are actually using the operating system's widgets and not drawing them itself. So if the native widget doesn't support this sort of thing, then wxPython's core widgets won't either.

You would need to create a custom widget that you draw yourself to get this functionality. Check out the wxPython demo for examples of custom widgets. All of the widgets in AGW are custom, for example.

Comment: .....i have checked it in google as I am not aware of that AGW library ..but i cant find the way to do so.... can u tell me how can i make my custom widget with that AGW

Comment: I'm not saying you can use AGW to create a custom widget. I just gave those set of widgets as an example that you can use for ideas. I would ask on the wxPython Google group for additional assistance. There are several people there who have created custom widgets.

Comment: thank you dear.... i found a way to do so... i can set background image and place the textxtrl with same background colour ... it is not that much accurate but still it look nice